# Changing font while drawing paragraph in Java

Tags: java, layout, graphics, fonts, draw

I am rendering a paragraph and, for word wrapping, I am using the    `LineBreakMeasurer` and the `TextLayout` class.
This is the snippet that I am using , which is easily available online :

```
 void drawParagraph(Graphics2D g, String paragraph, float width) {
    LineBreakMeasurer linebreaker = new LineBreakMeasurer(new AttributedString(paragraph)
        .getIterator(), g.getFontRenderContext());

    int y = 0;
    while (linebreaker.getPosition() < paragraph.length()) {
      TextLayout textLayout = linebreaker.nextLayout(width);

      y += textLayout.getAscent();
      textLayout.draw(g, 0, y);
      y += textLayout.getDescent() + textLayout.getLeading();
    }
  }
```

However, I am facing a problem, when I am trying to change the font.
Although i am changing the font by invoking `g.setFont(new Font(...))`, the paragraph is not being rendered in that font. However, when I try to use `g.drawString()`, it is working as expected.

Please help me with this problem.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the fonts in your AttributedString.  For instance:

```
AttributedString text = new AttributedString(paragraph);

Font emphasis = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 12);
int emphasisStart = 30;
int emphasisEnd = 42;
text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, emphasis, emphasisStart, emphasisEnd);

LineBreakMeasurer linebreaker =
    new LineBreakMeasurer(text.getIterator(), g.getFontRenderContext());
```